# Establish connection between textfield value of webparts to be assign into listfield in NewForm.aspx or EditForm.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-designer, visual-studio, content-query-web-part

Textfield is present in webpart (which is inside NewForm.aspx or EditForm.aspx), when I click on submit button on webpart then that value gets displayed in listfield (inside specific column) of  NewFom.aspx or EditForm.aspx .

Answer (score 1):

You can use SPQuery to connect text fields and list items..
http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/06/25/spquery-examples-sharepoint-2010-client-object-model/